# system / pipe call changes special characters in command passed for execution

Tags: c++, c, linux, bash

I wanted to use system / pipe command to execute command which has special characters. below is the sample code. 
After executing the command through system / pipe, it changes the command by changing special characters.
I am surprised to see that system command is changing the text passed as command.

```
run(char *cmd)
{
    FILE *in;
    extern FILE *popen();
    char buff[2048]= {0,};

if(!(in = popen(cmd, "r")))
{
    exit(1);
}

while(fgets(buff, sizeof(buff), in)!=NULL)
{
    printf("%s", buff);
}
    pclose(in);
}

main()
{
    char cmd[2048]={0,};

    sprintf(cmd,"echo \"'http://1.2.3.4/files-spaces-specialchars-      
    ascii/%23@%23@@!@!@!@%23%23$$$$$$$ASA(() 
    (!FreemakeAudioConverterSetup.exe'\" >>/tmp/logger 2>&1");
    printf("this is CMD:[%s]\n",cmd);
    system("echo "" > /tmp/logger"); /* to clear file containt */
    system(cmd);
    run(cmd);
}
```

OUTPUT

```
[terminal]$ ./a.out
this is CMD:[echo "'http://1.2.3.4/files-spaces-specialchars-ascii/%23@%23@@!@!@!@%23$$$$$$$ASA(()(!FreemakeAudioConverterSetup.exe'" >>/tmp/logger 2>&1]

[terminal]$ cat /tmp/logger
'http://1.2.3.4/files-spaces-specialchars-ascii/%23@%23@@!@!@!@%23538853885388(()(!FreemakeAudioConverterSetup.exe'

'http://1.2.3.4/files-spaces-specialchars-ascii/%23@%23@@!@!@!@%23538953895389(()(!FreemakeAudioConverterSetup.exe'
[terminal]$
```

As shown above the original command URL is getting changed after executing through system / pipe command.

Any inputs from developers?

Comment: I guess your shell did the conversion.

Comment: The dollar sign tells the shell to perform the expansion of the given variable. Now, the variable `$` is special to the shell: it contains the PID of the running shell… so each `$$` that appear will be expanded to the PID of the running shell. You can actually see that each `$$` is expanded to `5388` in the first call and to `5399` in the second call. To forbid shell expansion, enclose the string in single quotes or escape the dollar signs (all of them). However, what you're trying to achieve is not really clear, and you're very likely doing it wrong.

Comment: Also, the format string '%23$' does not have a conversion specification and so prints nothing.  (But consumes one of the $)

Comment: @gniourf_gniourf : Thanks for your valuable inputs. Here the shell is converting $$ to PID of running shell. As you said we have to use single quotes or escape sequence around dollar sign. But here its possible for complete URL and not for particular $$ signs.  As you can see I have already convered the URL with single quotes but still the behaviour is same. Still I will try in different ways. ____ This is sample code of what we use in our project work. And this string is dynamic and not constant.

Comment: No, you haven't quoted the url with single quotes! That's because the single quotes occur _inside double quotes,_ hence the single quotes have no particular meaning there. Try it in your terminal: `echo "'$$'"`, vs `echo '$$'`.

Comment: That's correct. My bad. I am using only single quotes now. Which is working fine. Thanks a lot. :)

Comment: the proper signature for the `main()` function is never `main()`.  However, it can be `int main()`  or better: `int main( void )`.. in a similar vein, ALL functions have a return type, even if it is `void`  so the signature for the `run()` function should be: `void run( char *cmd )`

Comment: for ease of readability and understanding by us humans, please indent the code consistently.

Comment: regarding this line: `char cmd[2048]={0,};`  1) 0 is not a char, it is (depending on the underlying architecture( 4 or 8 characters.  Perhaps you meant: `char cmd[2048]={'\0'};`

Comment: when asking a question about a runtime problem, always post code that cleanly compiles,  The posted code does not even come near to cleanly compiling.   Starting with it is missing the statements: `#include <stdio.h>` and `#include <stdlib.h>`

Comment: a char array initializer cannot be across line breaks with out a full set of "s around each part of the initializer

Comment: the function: `sprintf()` requires 3 parameters, however the posted code (even when freely examined) only has 2 parameters. Suggest: `sprintf(cmd, "%s", "echo \"'http://1.2.3.4/files-spaces-specialchars-"
                "ascii/%23@%23@@!@!@!@%23%23$$$$$$$ASA(()"
                "(!FreemakeAudioConverterSetup.exe'\" >>/tmp/logger 2>&1");

Comment: Answers is in 2nd comment only. If we use Single quote instead of double quotes code works fine as per the requirement.  **ANSWER:**                              `sprintf(cmd,"echo 'http://1.2.3.4/files-spaces-specialchars-      
    ascii/%23@%23@@!@!@!@%23%23$$$$$$$ASA(() 
    (!FreemakeAudioConverterSetup.exe' >>/tmp/logger 2>&1");`

Answer (score 0):

correcting the code, so it cleanly compiles results in:

Note: I also added a call to `perror()` so if the call to `popen()` fails the user is properly notified of what happened.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void run(char *cmd)
{
    FILE *in;
    extern FILE *popen();
    char buff[2048]= {'\0'};

    if(!(in = popen(cmd, "r")))
    {
        perror( "popen for read failed" );
        exit(1);
    }

    while(fgets(buff, sizeof(buff), in)!=NULL)
    {
        printf("%s", buff);
    }

    pclose(in);
}

int main( void )
{
    char cmd[2048]={'\0'};

    sprintf(cmd, "%s", "echo \"'http://1.2.3.4/files-spaces-specialchars-"
                "ascii/%23@%23@@!@!@!@%23%23$$$$$$$ASA(()"
                "(!FreemakeAudioConverterSetup.exe'\" >>/tmp/logger 2>&1");
    printf("this is CMD:[%s]\n",cmd);
    system("echo "" > /tmp/logger"); /* to clear file containt */
    system(cmd);
    run(cmd);
}
```

then running that code results in:

```
this is CMD:[echo "'http://1.2.3.4/files-spaces-specialchars-ascii/%23@%23@@!@!@!@%23%23$$$$$$$ASA(()(!FreemakeAudioConverterSetup.exe'" >>/tmp/logger 2>&1]
```

and cat `/tmp/logger` results in:

cat /tmp/logger

```
'http://1.2.3.4/files-spaces-specialchars-ascii/%23@%23@@!@!@!@%23%23193951939519395(()(!FreemakeAudioConverterSetup.exe'
'http://1.2.3.4/files-spaces-specialchars-ascii/%23@%23@@!@!@!@%23%23193961939619396(()(!FreemakeAudioConverterSetup.exe'
```